# Difference between Element node and Text Node

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "validator.dtd">

<people>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <course>Computer Technology</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <student>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>
</people>
```

In simple XML language `<open-tag> data </open-tag>` is an element.
As per my XML above, `<student> ... </student>` is an element and so are the other tags.

In DOM parsing, there is an `Element` node and a `Text` node. Referring to the book I am using, `<student>` is an `Element` node and `<name>`, `<course>` and the other nested tags are `Text` nodes.

So, if I am understanding DOM properly, all the outer tags are `Elements` and the tags that contain the actual data are `Text` nodes ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the XML elements present in a XML is an element node. The text present in the XML elements are text nodes.

Comment: So, in DOM, everything turns into a node of some type ? Attributes, values, etc and is represented by a specialized `Node` with type being determined by `getNodeType()` ???

Comment: @LittleChild: Yes they are you can see the w3 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1312295772

Comment: @LittleChild: Node is the base class for all xml representations

Answer (score 15):

This xml `<people><student><name></name></student></people>` has no text nodes.

This xml `<people><student><name>John</name></student></people>` has one text node `John`

This xml

```
<people>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
    </student>
</people>
```

has 5 text nodes, text node 1 is spaces and CRLF between `<people>` and `<student>` and so on