# python text.strip() returns empty

Tags: xml, document, label

Good morning everyone;
I'm trying to extract SGML documents using this code, but I got empty documents as a result, this is my python code :

```
from os import listdir
from os import makedirs
from os.path import isfile, join
from re import sub
import ast
import numpy
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True) # escaping malformed strings
pathCol="C:/Users/Desktop/FR"
pathExtr="C:/Users/Desktop/FRExt"
i=0
for f in listdir(pathCol):
    with open(join(pathCol,f), 'r') as f:   # Reading file
        xml = f.read()

    xml = '<ROOT>' + xml + '</ROOT>'   # Let's add a root tag
    root = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
    for doc in root:
        try :
            docNo=doc.find('DOCNO').text.strip()
        except :
            i+=1
            docNo="LATIMES"+str(i)
        try : 
            text=doc.find('TEXT').text.strip()
        except :
            try :
                text=doc.find('HEADLINE').text.strip()
            except :
                try :
                    text=doc.find('GRAPHIC').text.strip()
                except :
                    text=" "

        fi=open(join(pathExtr,docNo),'w')
        fi.write(text)
        fi.close()
        print("%s OK" %(docNo))
    f.close()
```

And this is a structure of a sample document :

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO> LA010189-0001 </DOCNO>
<DOCID> 1 </DOCID>
<DATE>
<P>
January 1, 1989, Sunday, Home Edition 
</P>
</DATE>
<SECTION>
<P>
Book Review; Page 1; Book Review Desk 
</P>
</SECTION>
<LENGTH>
<P>
1206 words 
</P>
</LENGTH>
<HEADLINE>
<P>
NEW FALLOUT FROM CHERNOBYL; 
</P>
<P>
THE SOCIAL IMPACT OF THE ...
</P>
</HEADLINE>
<BYLINE>
<P>
By James E. ... 
</P>
</BYLINE>
<TEXT>
<P>
The onset of the new Gorbachev policy of glasnost,... 
</P>
...
</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
... etc
</DOC>
```

I want to get the content between `<TEXT>` labels for each document between `<DOC>` and `</DOC>`, instead I've got empty documents :(
Please, is there someone that can help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920496/difference-between-element-node-and-text-node) in the `//ROOT/DOC/TEXT` `Element`, that's why `doc.find('TEXT').text` returns an empty string.

Instead, there are [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) nodes (aka `<P>`) that you can iter through.

Finally, to 'stringify' an `Element`, you can use [`ET.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring)

**TLDR**

```
text = ''.join(map(ET.tostring, doc.find('TEXT'))).strip()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'll try like this.