# Selenium for Python: Get text() of node that is shared with another element, via XPath

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

On this **[page](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251712/?referrer=tickerSearch)** I would like Selenium for Python to grab the text contents of the "*Investment Objective*", excluding the `<h3>` header. I want to use XPath.

The nodes look like this:

```
<div class="carousel-content column fund-objective">
    <h3 class="carousel-header">INVESTMENT OBJECTIVE</h3>
    The Fund seeks to track the performance of an index composed of 25 of the largest Dutch companies listed on NYSE Euronext Amsterdam.
</div>
```

To retrieve the text, I'm using:

```
string = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

---

If use I the this XPath for the top node:

```
xpath = '//div[@class="carousel-content column fund-objective"]'
```

It will work, but it includes the `<h3>` header `INVESTMENT OBJECTIVE` — which I want to exclude.

---

However, if I try to use `/text()` to address the actual text content, it seems that Selenium for Python doesn't let me grab it whilst using the `.text` to get the attribute:

```
xpath = '//div[@class="carousel-content column fund-objective"]/text()'
```

*Note that there seems to be multiple nodes with this XPath on this particular page, so I'm specifying the correct node like this:*

```
xpath = '(//div[@class="carousel-content column fund-objective"]/text())[2]'
```

My interpretation of the problem is that `.text` doesn't allow me to retrieve the text contents of the XPath sub-node `text()`. My apologies for incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/text()` will locate and [return text node, which is not an element node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920496/difference-between-element-node-and-text-node). It doesn't have `text` property.

One solution will be to locate both elements and remove the unwanted text

```
xpath = '//div[@class="carousel-content column fund-objective"]'
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
all_text = element .text
title_text = element.find_element_by_xpath('./*[@class="carousel-header"]').text

all_text.replace(title_text, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to get required output:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="carousel-content column fund-objective"])[2]')
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', div).strip()
```

The output is

```
'The Fund seeks to track the performance of an index composed of 25 of the largest Dutch companies listed on NYSE Euronext Amsterdam.'
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the text **The Fund seeks to track the performance of an index composed of 25 of the largest Dutch companies listed on NYSE Euronext Amsterdam.** you can use the following line of code :

```
string = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='carousel-content column fund-objective' and not (@class='carousel-header')]").text
```